# Regular Expression for date in python?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, pandas, python-2.7

How to check date value in pandas dataframe through regex and pick wrong date type values?

date: df

```
Date_col
22-01-2016
2016-01-22
2016/01/22
2018-12-25 09:27:53
22-Jan-2016
abcd
1203
2072006
20030201
```

output:

```
Bad_Date
22-Jan-2016
abcd
1203
2072006
20030201
```

may be regular expression which allows only numbers,'-'
,'/', ':' would work out this problem.

Comment: Are you looking to verify whether a column simply has a specific date-like format or are you looking to validate correct dates as well?

Comment: For example, is `2019-02-30` a bad date? What about `2018-45-12`?

Comment: Will you be accounting for leap years?

Comment: Do you care about the year 10,548? such as `10548-01-01`?

Comment: It should contain proper date format either 22-07-2019 or 2019-07-22 other than this it would be a bad date.

Comment: I am looking for regular expression which only allows combination of numbers[0-9] with (-,/,:). I think solve my problem. Other than this is a bad date.

Comment: So `[0-9]+([\/:-])[0-9]+\1[0-9]+` would solve the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One idea could be to see which values `pandas.to_datetime` rejects:

```
import pandas as pd

bad_times = []
for i in df.Date_col.values:
    try:
        pd.to_datetime(i)
    except ValueError:
        bad_times.append(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `str.contains` with `regular expressions`:

```
wrong_dates1 = ~df['Date_col'].str.contains('[-/:]')   # rows without the characters -, /, :
wrong_dates2 = df['Date_col'].str.contains('[A-Za-z]') # rows with letters

df[wrong_dates1 | wrong_dates2]
```

```
      Date_col
4  22-Jan-2016
5         abcd
6         1203
7      2072006
8     20030201
```

---

**side note**

If you would consider `22-Jan-2016` and `20030201` as valid dates (which they are), you can simply use `pd.to_datetime` with `errors='coerce'` which casts invalid dates tot `NaT`:

```
bad_dates = pd.to_datetime(df['Date_col'], errors='coerce').isna()
df[bad_dates]
```

```
  Date_col
5     abcd
6     1203
7  2072006
```